# Reorder the position of title,thumbnail and price in woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce

I am working with wordpress woocommerce. I have to customize the shop page of the website. In which I have to place the featured image below the title and price. I try few things for that but that not work for me.

I try to change the priority of thumbnail in function.php file like below

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );    
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 90 );
```

This is also not works for me infact its double the featured image on shop page. Can anybody please tell me how can I reorder the shop page 's thumbnail,title, price in woocommerce?

Answer (score 1):

Let try this and see it.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 90 );
```

Comment: I add this in function.php and see the result http://prntscr.com/fxzmbn

Comment: When it is duplicate just adding some css it will do trick solved you problem. Here is the CSS file you need to updated on you backend    
[  .product-images {
    display: none;
}]